# Is there a cleaner way to iterate through all binary 4-tuples?

Tags: python

This does what I want it to do:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product(*[[0,1]]*4))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 1, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

But it's a bit obfuscated to me. Is there a more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if it looks obfuscated, it's probably Python.

Comment: I don't think Python is obfuscated. It's even on the Zen, `Simple is better than complex.`. For me reading python code is as simple as reading a pseudo-code, it's said to be a functional pseudo code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`itertools.product` takes a `repeat` argument which simplifies it a bit as it avoids the argument unpacking and therefor the list multiplication:

```
itertools.product(range(2), repeat=4)
```

This is even called out in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)<sup>1</sup> (though the example uses `repeat=3`).

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note, I used `range(2)` rather than `(0, 1)` or `[0, 1]` since that's how it's written in the documentation.  Either way will work :) (obviously)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's this:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=4))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 1, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Can't get much simpler than that :).

Comment: This hardly looks different at all.

Comment: `itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=4)` looks cleaner than `itertools.product(*[[0,1]]*4)`, at least to me. `itertools.product` is the right solution, so it's not going to look too different from the OP's version.

Comment: @Octopus : hmmmm, I thought that octopuses had [superior vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod_eye), but it seems that you do have a blind spot :).

Comment: I would use `from itertools import product`.

Comment: @f.rodrigues, so might I, depending on the circumstance; but I don't think that affects how Pythonic the code is either way, so I just followed the OP's lead, for clarity.

Comment: Yes indeed, but `produtc(...)` is a lot cleaner than `itertools.product(...)`, anyone with some minor math background understand what a product is, while to understand that there's a module, which has a function/method which does something that is make product... well that's a long way.

Comment: @f.rodrigues, I'm using `itertools.product` because the OP is using `itertools.product`, so obviously the OP understands how it works :). I was sort of following the principle of least astonishment. Also, `itertools.product` is not to product as `sum` is to sum.

Answer (score 1):

If it's *clarity* you're after:

```
for  a in range(2):
  for b in range(2):
    for c in range(2):
      for d in range(2):
        tup = (a,b,c,d)
        print(tup)
```

And if you don't like nesting but do like list comprehensions:

```
[ (d,c,b,a) for d in range(2) for c in range(2) for b in range(2) for a in range(2) ]
```

And if you want to emphasize *binary*

```
for i in range(16):
    t=(1 if (i & 8) else 0, 
       1 if (i & 4) else 0, 
       1 if (i & 2) else 0, 
       (i & 1)
      )
    print( t)
```

Comment: I don't think more code / verbosity equals clarity.

Comment: "explicit is better than implicit" (from "the Zen of Python").  My ways, you don't have to know anything about itertools.product, so it's clearer to anyone who knows Python language  but not itertools. Note the one-line list comprehension, if you want "flat is better than nested" as well. Agreed, at the end of the day, it's opinion not fact, and YMMV.

Comment: The OP does know `itertools.product` though, and even if not, I think it's easier to understand once you explain it. But I see your point :). Also, that list comprehension is still nested :P.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way:

```
>>> [tuple(format(x,'04b')) for x in range(16)]
[('0', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '1'), ('0', '0', '1', '0'), ('0', '0', '1', '1'), ('0', '1', '0', '0'), ('0', '1', '0', '1'), ('0', '1', '1', '0'), ('0', '1', '1', '1'), ('1', '0', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '0', '1'), ('1', '0', '1', '0'), ('1', '0', '1', '1'), ('1', '1', '0', '0'), ('1', '1', '0', '1'), ('1', '1', '1', '0'), ('1', '1', '1', '1')]
```

if you don't mind strings...

Or just convert if you do want ints:

```
>>> map(tuple, (map(int, format(x,'04b')) for x in range(16)))
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```